# An example of transformation matrix of polynomial derivatives.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

> Let $V=\{f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}| \exists a_0,...,a_4\in \mathbb{R},f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{4}a_ix^i \}$, we define the linear map $\phi:V \rightarrow V$ as follows:
> $$\phi(f)(x)=f''(x)+xf'(x)-f(x+1). $$
> Determine a Basis $B$ for $V$ and determine the transformation matrix $[\phi]_{B}^{B}.$

I'm not sure if my process makes any sense so I wanted to ask if I had made any mistakes. Since we're interested in generated polynomials up to degree four I thought the simplest basis would be $B=\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4 \}$. Since the columns of the transformation matrix are the images of $B$ under $\phi$, I proceeded by just finding the image of every vector of the basis.
$$\phi(1)(x)=0,\ \phi(x)(x)=-1,\ \phi(x^2)(x)=2+2x^2-(x+1)^2, \\ \phi(x^3)(x)=6x+3x^3-(x+1)^3, \ \phi(x^4)(x)=12x^2+4x^4-(x+1)^4 $$
Translating this into a matrix I got: $$\begin{pmatrix}0&-1&-1&-1&-1 \\0&0&-2&3&-4 \\0&0&1&-3&6\\0&0&0&2&-4\\0&0&0&0&3
\end{pmatrix} $$
But as I said I'm not sure if the end result is correct I'd appreciate if someone could verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have the right idea about going from the image of each basis vector to the matrix representation of the transformation, but your calculations for the images are incorrect. You should have
$$
\phi(x^{0})(x) = -1 \\
\phi(x^{1})(x) = -1 \\
\phi(x^{2})(x) = 1 - 2 x + x^{2} \\
\phi(x^{3})(x) = -1 + 3 x - 3 x^{2} + 2 x^{3} \\
\phi(x^{4})(x) = -1 - 4 x + 6 x^{2} - 4 x^{3} + 3 x^{4}
$$
With that, we end up with the corresponding matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\color{red}{-1}&-1&\color{red}{1}&-1&-1 \\0&0&-2&3&-4 \\0&0&1&-3&6\\0&0&0&2&-4\\0&0&0&0&3
\end{pmatrix}. 
$$

Comment: Thank you, I expected my mistakes to be much worse.